# Buying used Mac mini to run latest Xcode

Tags: xcode, mac-mini

I want to get into iOS development, but unfortunately my laptop is running Windows 10 and I don't want to deal with virtual machines and other headaches related to developing with Xcode on Windows. I want to develop for iOS in a native apple environment. I also want it to run the newest version of Xcode.

So I've decided I will buy a used Mac mini, but I don't know exactly which is and isn't necessary. Also, I don't want to deal with buying a lower end Mac mini (one which doesn't fit the requirements) and upgrading it myself, since I have never done anything like that before and I don't need crazy computer power anyway. So basically....

How much memory do I need? How much memory does Xcode take up? Xcode is basically the only thing I will need on there, iOS development stuff only.

How much ram does it need to run comfortably? obviously not 1 or 2 GB like some older ones, does 4 GB or 8 GB work?

All the other computer terms like *2.26GHz Core2Duo and 128 GB SSD*, are those relevant for my needs? If so are they enough?

I don't have a budget but I would ideally like to spend around 300ish including price of mac mini, monitor, keyboard and mouse.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- When I open only Chrome and XCode with a small project, my Mac uses 3.2GB of memory. You don't want swapping. If you only want to do simple programming, 4G of memory will work fine. You will want to be able to open Stack Exchange in the background...
- The standard SSD and CPUs will do
- Make sure your system is compatible with the latest OSX. If it is not, you cannot test compatibility with the latest version and might not be able to upload your software to App Stores. I would buy a version that I expect to be supported in the next OSX software update.
  (currently Mac mini 2010 or newer, at least)

So, in short, Mac Mini 2010+, 4G, better 8G of ram. First hit online sais 260$, so that's around your budget.

Comment: OK I'll keep that in mind thanks for the feedback!